# JGit Push messages

Tags: jgit

Am trying to push using JGit.  However my PushResults never has the messages assosiated with Push.  For example how do I get the message "Everything-up-to-date" when my push has nohing new.
Basically I want to get the result messages from JGit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I kind of figured from the code that those messages are written by Push.java under the option that Verbose is set to true.  But I couldn't find a way to set verbose on.

Answer (score 2):

`PushResult#getMessages()` returns *additional* messages sent from the remote. Gerrit for example would send a message that explains why a push was rejected.

In order to obtain the result of a push operation you can call `PushResult#getRemoteUpdates()`. It returns a `RemoteRefUpdate` that holds the status for each ref that was to be updated.

Does that answer your question?